# Progress 11.6 procedure and appBuilder, compiler result window font is far too small

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with appBuilder/procedure editor for Progress release 11.6 (I'm **not** working with Progress Studio). When I launch the compiler, the compiler result window which comes up is unreadably small, as you can see in following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

How can I make this readable? (Larger font size)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try this: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P124422

Comment: Your comment seems to be right. Please write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a KB article from Progress on this issue [here](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P124422). The resolution as per the article is to ensure DefaultFont and the DefaultFixedFont are defined in the .ini file with the desired sizes.