# How to customise table content dump in Progress-4GL database administration

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with Progress-4GL, and in there I'm dealing with quite a large table (+130 field, +8000 tuples).

In order to view that table, I've decided to dump the entries of that table and import this to Excel. This seems quite easy: just use "Data Administration", menu "Admin", menu item "Dump data and definition", "Table contents" (file extension: `*.d`).

But there's a catch: in the resulting `*.d` file, the fields are separated using a space, but there are some spaces in some fields, making the result "unimportable" in Excel. Therefore I'd like to separate the fields by a character which is certainly not used in that table (the pipe character ("|") is perfect for that.

Does anybody know how I can tell my general framework (OpenEdge Desktop, release 11.6, not any "Studio" IDE) to use another character as a separator in the `*.d` table contents dump?

Most probably this is to be done, using an entry in the Progress.ini file (as the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828595/progress-11-6-procedure-and-appbuilder-compiler-result-window-font-is-far-too-s)), but I don't know which entry I'm dealing with.

It would also be nice to have the column headers in that `*.d` table contents dump, is that even possible?

**Edit**
Meanwhile I've found out that some of the character fields contain newlines, causing the table content dump to be distributed over different lines. This, of course, makes the whole thing unusable. Is there any way not to go to a new line in the `*.d` file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check Admin->Export Data->Text menu item in Data Administration tool. You can select "All" for "Fields to Export" option. The "Field Delimiter" can be left empty and choose "|" as "Field Separator" (or any character of your choice). The only thing where this *might* fail is when a field's value is distributed over different lines.

Comment: Also, there is a KB article about this. It might help you: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P8426

Comment: @Austin: you're a life saver :-) Please described your comment about the "Admin, Export data" menu in an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `Admin->Export Data->Text` menu item in Data Administration tool. You can select "All" for "Fields to Export" option. The "Field Delimiter" can be left empty and choose "|" as "Field Separator" (or any character of your choice). The only thing where this might fail is when a field's value is distributed over different lines.

Also, there is a KB article about this. It might help: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P8426

Answer (score 3):

My favorite data format is json, unfortunately Excel cannot read json out of the box, but it can read xml.

Unfortunately, the Progress ABL methods write-json and write-xml do not work on database buffers, so you need to create a temp-table like your database table, buffer-copy the records across and then write-xml on the temp-table.

```
def var ctable as char no-undo initial "customer".

def var hq   as handle no-undo.
def var ht   as handle no-undo.
def var hbtt as handle no-undo.
def var hbdb as handle no-undo.

create buffer hbdb for table ctable.

create temp-table ht.
ht:create-like( hbdb ).
ht:temp-table-prepare( ctable ).
hbtt = ht:default-buffer-handle.

create query hq.
hq:add-buffer( hbdb ).
hq:query-prepare( "for each " + hbdb:name ).
hq:query-open().
do while hq:get-next( no-lock ):

  hbtt:buffer-create().
  hbtt:buffer-copy( hbdb ).

end.

ht:write-xml( "file", ctable + ".xml", true ).
```

Note that I am not cleaning up after myself.
You can add a filter to the query if necessary.
You can omit fields in the copy if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write code to do this yourself. The [EXPORT](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/EXPORT-statement.html) statement is your friend.

You can use something like the below. This is basically what the Data Dictionary does.

```
OUTPUT TO 'customer.psv'.    // choose your filename
FOR EACH Customer NO-LOCK:
    EXPORT DELIMITER '|' Customer.
END.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

If you wanted to write this generically/dynamically there's quite a bit more to do, and you'll probably end up using [buffer](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/Buffer-object-handle.html) and [buffer-field](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/Buffer-field-object-handle.html#Buffer-field-object-handle) handles, and [`PUT UNFORMATTED`](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/PUT-statement.html) .